# Connect Docker Image with Oracle Database on Host using pyodbc

Tags: docker, pyodbc

I have an application running on my machine that accesses a database using pyodbc. The application first reads from the database and later writes reusults back into the same database.

I would now like to run this application in the same way but in a docker image - but i cannot figure out how to create a connection between the docker container and the database.

Here is my **Docker file** (using info from [here](https://gist.github.com/stianlagstad/0978a151639f55a27672454fd46fcce9)):

```
FROM python:3.7.3

WORKDIR /usr/src

#add all required contents to directories

ADD results /usr/results
ADD data /usr/data
ADD src /usr/src

COPY drivers/mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.13-linux-ubuntu16.04-x86-64bit.tar.gz .
COPY drivers/oracle-instantclient12.2-basic-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm .
COPY drivers/oracle-instantclient12.2-odbc-12.2.0.1.0-2.x86_64.rpm .

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        unixodbc-dev

#unixODBC
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev unixodbc-bin unixodbc

# The oracle base driver needs this
RUN apt-get install -y libaio1

# Needed to install the oracle .rpm files
RUN apt-get install -y alien

#MySQL ODBC Ansi driver
RUN tar xvzf mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.9-linux-ubuntu16.04-x86-64bit.tar.gz \
    && ./mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.9-linux-ubuntu16.04-x86-64bit/bin/myodbc-installer -d -a -n "MySQL ODBC 5.3 Ansi Driver" \
        -t "DRIVER=/usr/src/app/mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.9-linux-ubuntu16.04-x86-64bit/lib/libmyodbc5a.so"

# Oracle 12.2
# 1. Install the oracle instant client
RUN alien -i oracle-instantclient12.2-basic-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
RUN alien -i oracle-instantclient12.2-odbc-12.2.0.1.0-2.x86_64.rpm
# 2. Setup the client
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
# 3. Make sure links are set
RUN ldconfig
# 4. Use the myodbc-installer to install the driver
RUN ./mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.13-linux-ubuntu16.04-x86-64bit/bin/myodbc-installer -d -a -n "Oracle 12.2" -t "DRIVER=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libsqora.so.12.1"


#installing libraries
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install pyodbc
RUN pip install numpy 
RUN pip install datetime
RUN pip install -U scikit-learn
```

The **connection string** that I am using in my script is:

```
DRIVER={Oracle 12.2};UID=****;PWD=***;DSN=***;DBQ=*** ...
```

If I run my script from within the container, I get the following **Error Message:**

`('08004', '[08004] [unixODBC][Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified\n (12154) (SQLDriverConnect)'`

I can find very little information on how to connect a docker image to a database and any help would be greatly appreciated :)

If any additional information is necessary to answer this question please let me know. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Is hostname you provide for Oracle connection, is available inside container?
You can check it by ssh into running container ```docker exec -it <your_container_name> /bin/bash``` and then trying to telnet <hostname> <port> of your oracle connection.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What's the command to telnet? I tried `telnet <hostname> <port>` and get 'telnet command not found'

Comment: you can easily install telnet by ```apt-get update``` and ```apt-get install telnet```

Comment: for my container it shows ports 5000/tcp. when I now do `telnet <hostname><port>` I get  "No address associated with hostname". As `<hostname>` I put the output of running the `hostname` command in the command line

Comment: Do you have space between <hostname><port>. It should be like
```
telnet <yourdatabase_host> <port>
```